# Where to place/find debug library on Linux?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

On **Windows**, a debug library's name has a **d** as a postfix. But I don't know if there is a rule on **Linux**.

I know there is some *dbg* packages on **Debian**. For example, the library of the package *libjpeg62-dbg* is placed in `/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/libjpeg.so.62.0.0`. Is it a standard rule to place a debug version library into `/usr/lib/debug`?

And more. For example, if I run `pkg-config --libs opencv` that will return the **GCC** link options to me such as:

```
-L/usr/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann
```

It's very good. But I don't find a option in `pkg-config` which can return link options of those **debug** version libraries such as:

```
-L/usr/lib/debug -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann
```

Why `pkg-config` has not a option to return **debug** version of options if there is a standard rule about debug version library?

So, I want to know:

1. Is there a standard directory to place a debug library?
2. Are there some commands or options to process a debug library like `pkg-config --libs`?
3. How do you process the problem if the above two answers are no?

Thanks.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000335/how-to-use-debug-version-of-libc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Linux and windows have differing views on this. In Linux, there's really not much of a point in offering a debug library, because if someone really wants to debug the *library* they usually have the source code. Otherwise, you can mix and match (linking a "release" library with a "debug" program is just fine). You can be a nice guy and leave the debugging symbols in if you really want to (sysadmins can strip symbols out if they think there's too much bloat).

The other problem is that under linux there are too many compiler flags. There's not just "debug" and "release". There are a million flags you can turn on and off, as well as various target architectures. That's why most library developers just release the source code and let the user (or distro maintainer) decide what to turn on and off. In other words, there's no way your idea of a "debug" library would anticipate every developer's needs.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to link with a debug version of the library in order to use it, which is why `pkg-config` doesn't offer such an option. All you need to do is set up your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` appropriately when you run the program, and the debug library will get used at runtime.