# Is there any gdb helper script for libc functions?

Tags: android, linux, gdb

I'm trying to figure out parameters passed to a libc function, e.g

```
break XXX
command
printf "a=%p, b=%d ...\n", a, b
end
```

It's kinda lame, I had to write such thing for lots of functions.

Now I'm wondering if there's any helper script or any better way to see these functions in gdb? Just like how `strace` works

Comment: Recent GDB is scriptable in Python

Comment: You can run **info args** at the breakpoint, if your distro/development system includes debugging symbols for the library.

Comment: I tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000335/how-to-use-debug-version-of-libc)+the gdb command `info args` when I saw this interesting question. You need to install libc6-dbg and configure gdb such that it finds de libc symbols. I gave it a try but for some reason my gdb does not load the symbols...