# With a new custom compiled, builded version of glibc/libc.so, what happens during a “relocation has invalid symbol index” error?

Tags: c, gcc, glibc

From [the link](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Builds), I would like to compile a new glibc by myself. I know that compiling a glic is difficult, so on my first step, I would like to comiple a new glibc that match the exact same version already running on my linux system. I can skip toolchain dependency checking and start to focus on the glic iteself.

My ubuntu info is like:

```
    abbott@abbott-VirtualBox:/software/glibc/code$ uname -a
    Linux abbott-VirtualBox 4.4.0-31-generic #50~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 01:07:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    abbott@abbott-VirtualBox:/software/glibc/code$ lsb_release -a
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
    Release:    14.04
    Codename:   trusty
```

The already existed glibc is: 2.19. check the version like:

```
abbott@abbott-VirtualBox:/software/glibc/code$ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.9) 2.19
```

I prepare a very simple c code for testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
        long z; printf("Long int size is %i bytes long!\n", sizeof(z)); 
        return 0;
}
```

I compile this code using the already existed gcc,

```
gcc simple.c
```

I goe the "a.out", it's ok. it's runnable it's wonderful:

```
abbott@abbott-VirtualBox:/software/glibc/code$ ldd a.out
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffceaf0b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1a66f64000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055b9118c7000)
```

So, I download from [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.19.tar.gz), I choose the "glibc-2.19.tar.gz".

I put the source at
 `/software/glibc/glibc-2.19`

compile at 
    `/software/glibc/compile-2.19`

compile result is OK:

```
abbott@abbott-VirtualBox:/software/glibc/compile-2.19$ ../glibc-2.19/configure -prefix=/usr
abbott@abbott-VirtualBox:/software/glibc/compile-2.19$ make
```

In the "compile-2.19" folder, there is a testrun.sh shell code,
 I follow the "Compile normally, run under new glibc" section in the [link](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Builds), it's ok, it works.

```
abbott@abbott-VirtualBox:/software/glibc/compile-2.19$ ./testrun.sh ../code/a.out
```

I follow the "Compile against glibc build tree" section in the [link](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Builds),

```
GLIBC=/software/glibc/compile-2.19

gcc \
  -Wl,-rpath=${GLIBC}:\
${GLIBC}/math:\
${GLIBC}/elf:\
${GLIBC}/dlfcn:\
${GLIBC}/nss:\
${GLIBC}/nis:\
${GLIBC}/rt:\
${GLIBC}/resolv:\
${GLIBC}/crypt:\
${GLIBC}/nptl:\
${GLIBC}/dfp \
  -Wl,--dynamic-linker=${GLIBC}/elf/ld.so
  -o myligcsimple simple.c
```

It output:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 21
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I googled for several days, I cound not find the answers. some says that the main func is missing. but I have the main func, and the code works fine with the already existed glibc.

Question 1:

Would anybody help to find out how to fix the problem?

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
```

Comment: The instructions you link to are followed by "Please note that such a compilation does not make use of new headers or C runtime objects i.e. `crt1.o`, `crti.o`, and `crtn.o` provided by glibc. Changes made to headers or objects require a more complex compilation, see later instructions for the details." Given that the error reports your system `crt1.o`, my first thought would be to follow those later instructions.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, But I think it's a choose, not a must step.

Comment: Thanks for you replay, I use the piece of shell code in "thos later instructions", It gives me some idea. I need more time to dig into. very thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I follow the "Compile against glibc build tree" section in the link, ...
>   `/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info)`

Under *no circumstances* should your link use *any* objects from `/usr/lib/debug/`, and the command line arguments you show will certainly not cause that to happen. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10005800/50617).

Therefore, it is likely that you are not telling the whole story. Perhaps you've modified some environment variables, or the GCC driver, or you are not showing the actual command you used.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, That's the whole cmd I run. I didn't modify anything intentionally. maybe something changed andy I ignored. I read you answer of your link, but I don't think I get the point.