# gdb error: Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, gdb

I am having problems debugging a multi-threaded C++ application on an ARMv7 targets. The issue shows up on two different ARM targets, and I use different toolchains for them:

```
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

I've checked some threads, but (due to having the same issue with a minimalistic multithreading program) it seems that I 
* don't have a corrupted stack 
* any issues with virtual functions or function pointers

Mostly I'm using the target *Toradex Colibri iMX6* which has an *Angstrom Linux 2016.12* running on it.

**Questions**

- Is there something wrong with how I build the program?
- is there sth. wrong with how I'm using the `gdbserver` / `gdb`?
- which options do I have to fix the debugger output?

I debug via `gdbserver` on the target and the toolchain's `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb` on my host.
There's no native `gdb` for any of the targets.
I can build the application for *Linux x86*, but can't reproduce the bug so far on the PC.

### SW-problem

It seems that two of the threads are getting stuck, maybe due to a deadlock of two mutexes, or a thread trying to get one mutex a second time
(although that seems unlikely, the bug showed up after I've configured a mutex as *recursive*; I'll have to check for a second mutex used in that thread).

All other threads seem to keep running fine.

### SW-build and debug configuration

Build settings:

I'm using a toolchain provided by Toradex with `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++` and

```
-std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wpointer-arith -Wno-format-security -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wl,-Map=output.map -ggdb -g3 -fno-inline -O0
```

I pass the same program to the debuggers (i.e. to `gdbserver` on the target and to `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb` on the host)

```
$ (gdb) set sysroot </path/to/libs>
$ (gdb) file <binary>
$ (gdb) target remote IP:port
```

shared libraries:

For shared libraries, I've copied the `/usr/lib` and `/lib` from the target to the host. I've then downloaded the debug libraries which are available for the target/distribution and replaced the original shared libs with those.

```
(gdb) info sharedlibrary
From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x76fcf800  0x76feaa70  Yes         /path/to/libs/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
0x76fb9700  0x76fbcd2c  Yes         /path/to/libs/lib/librt.so.1
0x76f940c0  0x76fa2e0c  Yes         /path/to/libs/lib/libpthread.so.0
0x76f01630  0x76f72a10  Yes (*)     /path/to/libs/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
0x76e14d38  0x76e48028  Yes         /path/to/libs/lib/libm.so.6
0x76e041b0  0x76e0e7ec  Yes         /path/to/libs/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
0x76cd1000  0x76dc2b10  Yes         /path/to/libs/lib/libc.so.6
0x7449c96c  0x744a29e4  Yes         /path/to/libs/lib/libnss_files.so.2
(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.
```

I could not find a debug library for `libstdc++.so.6`.

### Debugging results

**Debug simple single-threaded application with crash on target:**

- works, i.e. does not report the error message from above

**Debug simple multi-threaded application, with or without deadlock, on target:**

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x76d6cd44 in uname () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
#1  0x00000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

**Debug the same simple multi-threaded application, with or without deadlock, on Linux-x86:**

- works

**Debug buggy application on PC:**

- seems to work, but we cannot reproduce the bug so far

**Debug the affected application on target:**

```
Thread 1 received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x76f9facc in __lll_robust_lock_wait (futex=0x257b94 <namespace1::function()::su_place+20>, private=0)
at /usr/src/debug/glibc/2.24-r0/git/nptl/lowlevelrobustlock.c:46
46    /usr/src/debug/glibc/2.24-r0/git/nptl/lowlevelrobustlock.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) thread apply all bt

Thread 6 (Thread 6606.6630):
#0  0x76d832c8 in __setreuid (ruid=8, euid=0)
at /usr/src/debug/glibc/2.24-r0/git/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/setreuid.c:29
#1  0x7efff06c in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 5 (Thread 6606.6629):
#0  0x76d55d44 in uname () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
#1  0x00000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 4 (Thread 6606.6628):
#0  0x76d55d44 in uname () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
#1  0x00000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 3 (Thread 6606.6627):
#0  0x76d55d44 in uname () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
#1  0x00000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 2 (Thread 6606.6626):
#0  __lll_robust_lock_wait (
futex=0x25b950 <namespace_2::a_function()::a_static_member+152>, private=128)
at /usr/src/debug/glibc/2.24-r0/git/nptl/lowlevelrobustlock.c:31
#1  0x00000080 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 1 (Thread 6606.6606):
#0  0x76f9facc in __lll_robust_lock_wait (futex=0x257b94 <namespace1::function()::su_place+20>, 
private=0) at /usr/src/debug/glibc/2.24-r0/git/nptl/lowlevelrobustlock.c:46
#1  0x00000002 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

**Update**

*I could find the bug (mutex deadlock) using `valgrind` with the PC-build of the SW.*

*However, the issue here is about the problems with `gdb`, which I could not understand or solve yet.*

Comment: Have you tried using memory debugging tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or similar?

Comment: No - `valgrind` is not available for the target platform.

Comment: Do you have a test suite on you x86 build platform against which you can run Valgrind?

Comment: If you can test your program on the host platform (as it seems in your question) then start there. Even if it seems to work Valgrind could point out some problem that happens only on the target system. And don't forget that Valgrind is *open-source* and could be rebuilt for a target it's not already built for (and it has quite a few of them already).

Comment: Have you seen and tried [this](https://fragglet.livejournal.com/19646.html)?

Comment: I could use `valgrind` on x86, but the thread issue doesn't occur there, so I did not really consider it yet. Cross-build `gdb` for ARM seems to be much effort - dunno about `valgrind`.

Comment: @Max Langhof: that seems worth a shot! thanks.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: unfortunately I could not repair the callstack on the ARM-target with the hints from [here](https://fragglet.livejournal.com/19646.html).

Comment: @radix It would be great if you post your finding. I am facing the same issue!

Comment: @abhiarora: With "issue" you refer to the mutex deadlock? Or the corrupted gdb frames?

Comment: Corrupted stack!

Comment: Well, unfortunately I did not find a solution. I handled the original problem with another approach and thus did not need the stack frames anymore.

Answer (score 3):

> I've then downloaded the debug libraries which are available for the target/distribution and replaced the original shared libs with those.

This is possibly the wrong thing to do (depending on what exactly you mean by "debug libraries"), and may be contributing to your problem. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10005800/50617).

As a first step, I would use the *exact* same libraries that you are using on the target, and check whether that changes the behavior of GDB.

Comment: I've originally been using the very same libraries as on the target - the results were even worse. Same error messages from `gdb`, and less detailed output from the libraries. The docu for `gdbserver` says that you can use a stripped binary on the target, only on the host you need a binary with debug information. I thought the same would apply for libraries.