# jni function calls some libc function which gdb does not know about

Tags: java, c, performance, file-io, jvm

I have a simple JNI function which I use to read data from file into `byte[]` from C code `UnixUtil.unsafeReadToByteArray` which is implemented as:

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_net_xxxxxxx_UnixUtil_unsafeReadToByteArray
  (JNIEnv *e, jclass jc, jint fd, jbyteArray array, jlong offset, jlong count){
  signed char *array_native_ptr = (*e) -> GetByteArrayElements(e, array, NULL);
  ssize_t bytes_read = read(fd, array_native_ptr + offset, (size_t) count);
  (*e) -> ReleaseByteArrayElements(e, array, array_native_ptr, 0);
  return bytes_read;
}
```

Profiling a java application running the function showed up some unclear result. Here is the top:

[image]

One of the hottest thing turned out to be some instruction by address `0x18eb1f` which is from `libc-2.27.so`. I wanted to understand what it was but gdb does not know about it

```
(gdb) disas 0x18eb1f
No function contains specified address
```

Objdump'ing libc to grep the address I found that

```
18eb0b:       72 0f                   jb     18eb1c <__nss_group_lookup@GLIBC_2.2.5+0x24ddc>
[...]
18eb1c:       48 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%rcx
18eb1f:       f3 a4                   rep movsb %ds:(%rsi),%es:(%rdi)
```

Which looks like it is a part of `__nss_group_lookup` while `__nss_group_lookup` seems not to contain the address:

```
(gdb) disas __nss_group_lookup
Dump of assembler code for function __nss_passwd_lookup:
   0x0000000000169d40 <+0>:     mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0x281121]        # 0x3eae68
   0x0000000000169d47 <+7>:     mov    DWORD PTR fs:[rax],0x26
   0x0000000000169d4e <+14>:    mov    eax,0xffffffff
   0x0000000000169d53 <+19>:    ret    
End of assembler dump. making the things more unclear then it was before.
```

making the things more unclear then before.

***Question:*** Can you give any hint where to look at to understand why is the instruction belonging to `__nss_group_lookup` is the hottest while calling to `jni_GetByteArrayElements`/`jni_ReleaseByteArrayElements` and what it actually is.

My expectation was since `jni_GetByteArrayElements`/`jni_ReleaseByteArrayElements` copies the `byte[]` from Java heap to C heap via `memcpy` it would be the hottest one.

Comment: It may just be that the debug symbols for your C library have not been installed.  These are packaged separately from the library itself in some Linux distributions and maybe in other environments.  On RedHat-family Linuxes, for example, you would want the package glibc-debuginfo.  Alternatively, you may need to [cause a special version of the C library to be used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10000335/2402272).  In one of these ways, it should be possible to make the wanted information available to `gdb`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It turned out to be the case. I did not know about where debug info come from before reading about `.symtab` and `.dynsym` sections so did not checked them... Also `/usr/lib/debug` did not contain the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently libc on your system does not contain debug symbols (there is no `.symtab` section in the shared library). Therefore gdb shows the nearest exported symbol from `.dynsym`, which has nothing to do with the actual hottest function.

`rep movsb` instruction suggests this fragment is a part of `memcpy` implementation.

Install `libc-dbg` package (or how it is called in your Linux distribution).

E.g. on my Ubuntu 18.04 the address `__nss_group_lookup+0x24ddc` indeed points to `memcpy` internals:

```
(gdb) disas __nss_group_lookup+0x24ddc
Dump of assembler code for function __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms:
   0x00007ffffef7ead0 <+0>:     mov    %rdi,%rax
   ...
   0x00007ffffef7eb1c <+76>:    mov    %rdx,%rcx
   0x00007ffffef7eb1f <+79>:    rep movsb %ds:(%rsi),%es:(%rdi)
   0x00007ffffef7eb21 <+81>:    retq
```

Comment: @SomeName BTW, have you tried [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler)? It also relies on perf-events, but unlike perf it is Java friendly, i.e. can show mixed Java+native+kernel stack traces.

Comment: No, not really tried, but heard about it, of course. Thank you.